# How can I trigger a pipeline of RepoA when something is pushed inside another repository RepoB within Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines, repository

I tried to figure this out, but came to no results. Does anyone know how to trigger a pipeline of a .NET project let's say RepoA when something is pushed inside another Repo called RepoB? I want to apply this feature to the pipeline of RepoA, because RepoB does not have a pipeline and I do not want a pipeline for RepoB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I trigger a pipeline of RepoA when something is pushed inside another repository RepoB within Azure DevOps?

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you can add the Repo B as Repo Resources in the pipeline of Repo A and set the trigger.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoB
    type: git
    name: MyProject/RepoB
    trigger:
     branches:
      include:
        - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: RepoB
- checkout: self
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Define a repositories resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource)

Comment: Thank you very much, your given example works quite well!